# POST API returning 404 (Not Found) when being used in app, works fine with CURL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, socket.io

I have a chat app that I'm working on that uses MongoDB, Express API and Socket.io for a backend. When I try to POST data to the API from within the app, it gives a 404 error and the request fails. But when I use CURL to try to POST data, it works and data is saved in MongoDB

Here's the server.js code where I create the API:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    }
  });

const Conversation = require('./database/ConversationModel');
const Message = require('./database/MessageModel');

mongoose
  .connect('<connection_string>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    server.listen(5173, () => {
      console.log('Server listening on port 5173');
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to connect to MongoDB:', error);
  });

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const { id } = socket.handshake.query;

  socket.join(id);

  socket.on('send-message', async ({ recipients, text }) => {
    try {
      // Save the message to the database
      const message = new Message({
        conversationId: recipients.join('-'),
        sender: id,
        text,
      });
      await message.save();

      // Emit the message to all recipients' sockets
      recipients.forEach((recipient) => {
        const newRecipients = recipients.filter((r) => r !== recipient);
        newRecipients.push(id);
        socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit('receive-message', {
          recipients: newRecipients,
          sender: id,
          text,
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending message:', error);
    }
  });
});

// API endpoints

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/api/conversations', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const conversations = await Conversation.find().populate('messages');
    res.json(conversations);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching conversations:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch conversations' });
  }
});

app.post('/api/conversations', async (req, res) => {
    const { recipients } = req.body;
  
    try {
      const conversation = new Conversation({
        recipients,
      });
      await conversation.save();
      res.status(201).json(conversation);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating conversation:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create conversation' });
    }
  });

app.post('/api/messages', async (req, res) => {
  const { conversationId, sender, text } = req.body;

  try {
    const message = new Message({ conversationId, sender, text });
    await message.save();
    res.status(201).json(message);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving message:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to save message' });
  }
});
```

Front-end/client code:

```
useEffect(() => {

    fetchConversations();
  }, []);

  async function fetchConversations() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/conversations');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch conversations');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setConversations(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching conversations:', error.message);
    }
  }

  function createConversation(recipients) {
    fetch('/api/conversations', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ recipients }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to create conversation');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('data')
        setConversations((prevConversations) => [
          ...prevConversations,
          data,
        ]);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error creating conversation:', error.message);
      });
  }
```

Conversation model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const conversationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  recipients: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Friend',
    required: true
  }],
  messages: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Message'
  }]
});

const Conversation = mongoose.model('Conversation', conversationSchema);

module.exports = Conversation;
```

I've tried testing the API multiple times and it works every time apart from when accessed from the client app

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question; questions should be self-contained here on stackoverflow and not rely on external sources to provide code. You don't need to share the entire file, only the sections that are relevant to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `fetch('/api/messages', {})`  : You didn't provided the backend host address, When using the fetch function without a host address, it assumes the current domain as the default host. try `fetch('{BACKEND_SEVER_URL}/api/messages', {})` to send the request to another server.

Comment: @PRATHEESHPC I'm using the same port number for my client as I am for the server. Should I host them on different ports? Or should I keep the same port but specify the URL regardless

Comment: You can't use same port for your client and server application, unless they are running in different servers. Try with different ports.

Comment: It doesn't look like your Express app is configured to statically serve a React app. They could only be using the same port if both were served by the same thing. If you use two different commands to start the front and back end, then they are two different services and therefore cannot share the same port

Comment: @Philisonstrike Ok thanks for the help, I'll try that. Just one thing though. When I'm setting the server up on a separate port, how should I specify the API link to use? Should I just do api.post('http://localhost:PORT/API/conversations')?

Comment: What do you mean _"I'll try that"_? I didn't suggest anything

Comment: You're getting ahead of yourself without providing necessary details about how you're **currently** running your apps. How do you start each app (frontend and backend)? Your Express app uses port 5173 but what does the React app use? Are you using a dev server from Webpack or Vite? How do you intend to deploy each app in production?

Comment: Sorry, yeah. I'm currently running my React app with Vite on the same port (5173). I meant I'll try running them on different ports to see if it'll work. Not sure yet how I'll deploy them into production

Comment: They cannot possibly be running on the same port. What URL do you open in your browser for the React app? Is your Express app actually running?

Comment: Well my React app is on http://localhost:5173 and my Express app is running so I really don't know how they are both running if they can't be on the same port

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out I just didn't realise that I had to run my client and server on different ports. I knew they had to be ran separately but I thought that just meant different processes and I'd had errors previously with running on different ports. Everything works now